# How to load all .yml files from resources directory at the time of application startup in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have 2-3 .yml files in resources directory in a spring application.
I want to load all these files at the application startup automatically.

I tried below code but did not work.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(YamlLoadApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:applicationTest,CountriesData",
                        "spring.config.location:src/main/resources/")
                .build().run(args);

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
```

Please help me to solve this. What is the best way to achive this? I would be using all these yml files values throughout the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue here `"spring.config.location:src/main/resources/"` sets `spring.config.location` to `src/main/resources/` which is not a class path resource but a file system resource. This is looked up from the current directory you're running your Spring Boot application from.

Several fixes:

Specify a full file system path like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
    applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(YmlsApplication.class)
        .properties("spring.config.name:applicationTest,CountriesData",
            "spring.config.location:/Users/msimons/tmp/configs/")
        .build().run(args);

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
    sources.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
}
```

Or specify a classpath resource. Notice that I put the config files under a separate directory, which lives in `src/main/resources/custom-config`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
    applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(YmlsApplication.class)
        .properties("spring.config.name:applicationTest,CountriesData",
            "spring.config.location:classpath:/custom-config/")
        .build().run(args);

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
    sources.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
}
```

Notice `classpath:` inside the path and also starting the directory at the root level of resources with `/`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It works for me now. is there any other way also to do this?

Comment: You can define those as command line parameters, i..e 
`java -jar target/ymls-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.name=CountriesData --spring.config.location=/Users/msimons/tmp/configs/`

or as environment parameters 
`SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=CountriesData SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=/Users/msimons/tmp/configs/ ./mvnw spring-boot:run`

Be aware btw that there is also `spring.config.additional-location`. In contrast to `location`, it adds the location and doesn't replace the default one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@PropertySource` annotation to externalize your configuration to a properties file.

Spring recommends using **Environment** to get the property values.

```
env.getProperty("mongodb.db");
```

You can mention the property files which are using in the class.

```
@Configuration
    @PropertySource({
        "classpath:config.properties",
        "classpath:db.properties"
    })
    public class AppConfig {
        @Autowired
        Environment env;
    }
```

From Spring 4 you can ignoreResourceNotFound to ignore the not found properties file

```
  @PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:missing.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true),
        @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
```

Examples are from the article - https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Refer the article if you need more information
[From Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)